# How to disable sticky corners in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I have 2 monitors and in Windows 7 I used to just mouse-flick maximized windows from one monitor to the other.

With Windows 8 however (charms disabled), my mouse hangs in the corners while doing this. This is because as described at the end of [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031120/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx), an "invisible barrier" of 6 pixels has now been added:

[image: Sticky Corners in Win8]

Thus I'm unable to have a smooth experience for window movement across monitors as I did back in Windows 7. (Both my monitors are aligned in the settings to the top, so that isn't the problem).

How do I disable the mouse from stopping in the corners when going from one monitor to the other?

Edit:
So it seems this is not possible without programming effort. I am currently writing a small tool to circumvent this nuisance. It's already working, I'm just touching up on the visuals :)

Edit2:
https://mouseunsticky.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not a solution to your exact problem, but an alternative way of doing this would be: Windows key + Shift + Left/Right arrow to quickly move apps from one monitor to the other.

Comment: And here I thought it was totally useless because the corners weren't big enough...

Comment: Codeplex link is broken.

Comment: Another windows 8 multi-monitor change is the addition of a MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed setting, which makes the cursor stick to the edge of a monitor when moved slowly. Disable it by setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop/MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed to 0

Answer (score 46):

You can get around this with a simple registry change.

If you wish to just change it for the current user find `MouseCornerClipLength` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\` and set the value to `0` (from `6`)

If you wish to disable it everywhere:

1. In registry, search: `MouseCornerClipLength`
2. Set the value to `0` (from `6`)
3. Repeat (there is more than one key with this name, I'm not sure which one(s) are necessary)
4. Restart

This stops your mouse catching and is perfect, you can still use the charms bar without issue on the outside edge of your monitors as easily as before (exactly as I wanted).

I created a thread a while ago about this [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-desktop/how-to-disable-hot-corners-on-dual-screen/69b45244-ffc7-4ac7-8473-d69c3799245b?msgId=8d4d2be9-7878-4a76-8429-0087ae27750b&page=2).

Comment: THANK YOU! You are a saviour. I had this annoying issue on multiple monitors with different resolutions, and almost banged my head. Thanks again!

Comment: A quick search indicates that it's actually a per-user setting, and you can set it for the current user at

 `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseCornerClipLength`

 The other results were in similar locations in `HKEY_USERS`, which would be the corresponding setting for other users.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. Lovely, smooth, top edge is back. Amazing how much something so simple can disrupt your work.

Comment: +1; I've found that I need to disable charms bar otherwise the mouse still sticks when moving to a monitor on the right of the current monitor.

Comment: This works perfectly for the top-right corner of my left monitor. However, my cursor still gets stuck in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix will not work in Windows 10. For that, there is [another SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/q/947817/45163).

Answer (score 6):

**Tested and working**

Open Regedit.

And go to`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Pannel/Desktop` search for a key named **MouseCornerClipLength** and change the value from 6 to 0.

Ok and restart the machine

Comment: Just a note that this one sets it for the current user.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name MouseCornerClipLength -Type DWORD -Value 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can download a third-party program called [Start 8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/). With it you can disable the sticky corners and you can also, if you want, get back the old Windows 7 style start menu.

It costs $5 but it has a free month trial.

Comment: That is incorrect. It let's you disable the hot corner charms, but not the sticky pixels.

Comment: The option is under Desktop >> Advanced. This worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called Skip Metro Suite. You can use it for diasbling all hot corners of Windows 8. You can download from here:
http://winaero.com/download.php?view.33

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Until someone comes out with a hack, this will continue to be a setting built into Windows 8. You'll unfortunately have to get used to watching those corners, and eventually this will become second nature.

Answer (score -3):

They can't be disabled. I wish we could vote on features to be added/removed from W8!