# Disable sticky corners in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable sticky corners in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8)

I'm trying windows 8.
As described at the end of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx). Windows 8 comes with an "invisible barrier" of 6 pixels at the corners:

[image]

I'd like to disable this functionallity. How can I do it?