# How can I stop missing the corners of my dual-monitor setup?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-server-2008

I have two monitors side-by-side at the same resolution. The problem with this setup is that Windows makes use of the far corners of all monitors for the Start Button, close buttons, desktop peek, etc., and I now often overshoot these.

How can I keep my dual-monitor setup, but prevent my mouse from switching screens when it's in a far corner?

I imagine that I am looking for some tool that prevents mousing over to the other screen when my cursor is within X pixels of the corner of a desktop. I have tried the following tools:

- [Dual Display Mouse Manager](http://ddmm.sourceforge.net/)
- [Mousenitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mousenitor/)

The problem is both of these seem to prevent mousing over to other screens across the *entire* border unless some condition is met; I'm looking *only* to affect the corners of the displays. Lastly, I'm not looking to tweak my resolutions or the positioning of my screens to accomplish this.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, I am running Windows 8 and Windows Server 2008, and would like a solution (though not necessarily the same one) for both setups.

Comment: So on solution is simply use the shortcuts for the Charms. The other is to simply use the hot spots on the other monitor. For instance the top right hot spot will exist in the same location fon both monitors.  A solution on Windows Server 2008 would require third-party software as thats based on Windows Vista.

Comment: I believe Windows 8 actually blocks some length of every corner by default. There was a question asking how to disable that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with Windows 8, this should be built-in as a 'sticky corners' feature, which applies to 6 pixels at each corner. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8) asks about disabling said feature.

The accepted answer to that question was to search for `MouseCornerClipLength` in the Registry and change each occurrence to 0. Here, you may wish to *extend* the blocked area, which would require setting a *larger* value, say 10 or 20.

A quick search indicates that it's actually a per-user setting, and you can set it for the current user at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MouseCornerClipLength
```

The other results were in similar locations in `HKEY_USERS`, which would be the corresponding setting for other users.

Answer (score -3):

In all honesty, the simplest solution is to learn to use the keyboard shortcuts. Windows 8 is no longer a mouse-oriented operating system, and pointing devices have become a second-class citizen to the keyboard and touch input.

Put the time into learning how to use the keyboard for these things, and you'll find it's far faster to do things than to use the mouse.

Pulling from [Microsoft's List of New Shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/new-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=t1) and a few pre-existing shortcuts from Windows 7:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd> To open the start menu
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open charms
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to peek at the desktop, and again to end the peek.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize a window
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to un-maximize a maximized window, or to minimize a non-maximized window.

Comment: I know the shortcuts, but often prefer using a mouse.