# How do I turn off cursor edge blocking when moving mouse slowly in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

In a multi-monitor set up on Windows 8.1 my mouse gets caught on the edges of screens if I move the mouse slowly (not just the corners). In theory this seems like a good feature, but I find it more irritating than useful.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Bonus: can the corners be turned off as well? I know I can turn off the functionality, but I can't turn off my mouse getting caught moving between monitors.

Comment: The monitors do not match size, so I understand that this difference will impact where the mouse can physically be allowed to move from monitor to monitor. I know you can move them up and down relative to each other.

Comment: They are top justified if that matters.

Comment: Ok that covers it

Comment: http://winaero.com/blog/fix-mouse-pointer-sticks-on-the-edge-when-moving-between-multiple-monitors/  see also the comments, and know that you would have to boot, or restart explorer . Because I cannot test this, would you please answer your own question, with what worked in full. (if it does)

Comment: Mouse Corner info is here http://superuser.com/questions/498576/how-to-disable-sticky-corners-in-windows-8