# Windows 10 mouse catches in corner

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 from 7. I have 2 monitors with the same resolution arranged horizontally.

If I move the mouse cursor to the top or bottom of one monitor, then try to move it to the other monitor, the mouse cursor catches in the corner and won't go to the other monitor. I need to move it slightly down or up to get to the other monitor. This is infuriating.

How do I fix the mouse corner issue?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498576/), which sounds similar, but it seems the settings have changed since Windows 8 as the solutions do not work for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to change the screen disposition so they can be aligned correctly with the physical setup that you have. To achieve this, you need to [Right-Click on your desktop, then click on Personalize]. From here, you should be able to dispose the screen like you want.

Comment: The screens are the same resolution and are directly side-by-side. Even if I shift one screen up a bit, if I try to mouse over from the bottom of that screen, it still catches as I have described.

Comment: Can you try to reset the display by disconnecting one screen, rebooting and connecting the screen again? If you don't go by the corner, are you still able to get to the other screen?